# windows phone webbrowser control images not displayed with incorrect extension

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am using webbrowser control to display and xhtml page. The page also has images. The issue is webbrowser is not able to display this image which is named as image.png. Upon investigating, i found that the mime of the image specifies that as a jpg. If i rename the png  to jpg, the image is dispalyed fine. But for me to do that, i'll have to rename all references to the image file in the xhtml. Is there a better solution available. Can webbrowser not recognize these kinds of files. Kindly help.